# How to run datatable api with default search value?

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I was wondering how to load datatable api with default search value. I tried something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
    $("input[type=search]").val('john')
});
```

But since, in order to show the search results the search box needs to be submitted. How do I this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering a `keyup` event...

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $("#datatable").DataTable();
    $("input[type='search']").val("john").trigger("keyup");
});
```

**EDIT**

I found a way to disable the pagination **when a search is active**.
Meaning when the search input field isn't empty.

I refined my solution to also hide the unsefull controls, considering a no-pagination dataTable.

See it on [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/GjbQWo/).

```
searchField.on("input",function(){

    // Grab the seach term (text inputed in the search field)
    searchTerm = $(this).val();
    console.log("searchTerm: "+searchTerm);

    // The paginate links and buttons...
    var paginate = $("#myTable").siblings('.dataTables_paginate');

    // Remove the whole table when search term is empty.
    if(searchTerm==""){
        console.log("searchField: empty");

        // Set pagination to desired length
        // and show controls.
        myTable.page.len( paginationLength ).columns.adjust().draw();
        paginate.show();
        pageLenghtSelect.show();
    }else{
        console.log("searchField: NOT empty");

        // Set pagination to no pagination at all (only one page).
        // and hide controls.
        myTable.page.len( -1 ).columns.adjust().draw();
        paginate.hide();
        pageLenghtSelect.hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: I just tryed on my side... It works with `keyup` and with `input` (the events), but doesn't with `keydown` or `keypress`.

Comment: Okay. I found another way to do it.

    `$('#datatable').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
 "oSearch": {"sSearch": searchText}
    });`

I put the user typed value in the variable `searchText`
But now, how do I turn the table to normal when the search box is cleared ?

Comment: Could you define «turn to normal»? Because, the way you've found is working too. I confirm. If «normal» refers to pagination being gone... Simply remove `"paging": false`, which disables pagination (it ain't helpfull in your search concern. ;)

Comment: I mean, after the user types in the search box, the pagination is gone. And I need the pagination back, when the search box is cleared. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: Do you really want to disable the pagination for this first onload search ?

Comment: I'm so sorry that I can't make it clear. All I want is, if the search input has any value, the pagination should be gone and when the search input doesn't have any value then the pagination should be there.

Comment: I found your answer... It's a no-can-do. *«The short answer is that you cannot alter initialisation options after the table has been initialised, unless there is an API available for it. You need to reinitialise the table.»* [Reference here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16373/enable-disable-features-after-initializing-the-table)

Comment: I also found something in a forum. [Here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/511). The person says that he did it by using this code `$pagination.show();` Condition was same but didn't work for me.

Comment: That is to show/remove the parent block. The thing is that even when pagination is impossible, like you do with `"paging": false`, the "previous" and "Next" links are still there. So, this is clearly something else. But I just gaot an idea to try... Hold on.

Comment: My try failed.... But the error I got lead my to **DataTable API** (which was clearly mentionned in your post... My bad, sorry, I just learned something too). [So your solution is certainly HERE](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()). Use "search" as event...

Comment: No problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I will edit my question soon... I have a CodePen almost working.

Comment: Here it is... I hope you'll like it!